# Do I lose the benefits of macro recording if I develop Excel apps in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel, vba

I've written lots of Excel macros in the past using the following development process:

1. Record a macro.
2. Open the VBA editor.
3. Edit the macro.

I'm now experimenting with a Visual Studio 2008 "Excel 2007 Add-In" project (C#), and I'm wondering if I will have to give up this development process.

**Questions:**

1. I know I can still record macros using Excel, but is there any way to access the resulting code in Visual Studio? Or do I just have to copy and paste then C#-ize it?
2. What happens with my "Personal Macro Workbook"? Can I use the macros I have stored in there within C#? Or is there some way to convert them to C#?
3. If there is some support for opening and editing VBA macros in Visual Studio, can you provide a very brief summary of how it works or point me to a good reference?
4. Do you have any other tips for transitioning from writing macros in VBA using Excel's built-in editor to writing them in C# with Visual Studio?

Comment: You'll have to C-sharp-ify your VBA if you're going with C# from VBA. If you go with VB.NET instead, you'll still need to make some minor adjustments to the original VBA. You can still use VBA in workbook specific solutions - though I'm not sure if the juice is worth the squeeze.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are in for a world of hurt, if you want to port VBA macros to C#.  If they are complex at all, I would just rewrite them in Visual Studio or keep them in Excel.

Also, as much as it pains me to say this, VB.net is really a better choice to do office development in at the moment.  VB.net supports *missing* parameters which will come in handy for the Excel methods with a zillion parameters.  This support will be added to C# for .NET 4.0.

You should be able to call a VBA method from .NET.  Take a look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608609.aspx

You can also look at this article on codeproject: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/extending_excel.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Scott. You convinced me to just stick with VBA until I upgrade to Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Glad to help.  I think you'll be happy with that decision.  It's not too long to wait anyways...

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I develop the Excel-DNA library.)

You should have a look at Excel-DNA - http://exceldna.codeplex.com. The library allows managed assemblies written in C#, VB.NET or F# to expose high-performance user-defined functions (UDFs) and macros to Excel through Excel's native .xll interface. The project is open-source and freely allows commercial use.

With your VBA background, it might make sense to move to .NET using VB.NET first. Once you've made this shift, starting to use C# will be much easier and you can cross-reference assemblies written in VB.NET and C# with no problems.

Some add-in tools like ReSharper, and the free .NET IDE [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/), can even convert code from VB.NET to C# automatically. Certainly for using the COM automation interface from C# you want to use .NET 4.

Mike Staunton has a video of a talk discussion the VBA -> VB.NET via Excel-DNA technique here: http://www.thalesians.com/finance/index.php/Events/Seminars/Seminar27#Video.